# Where can I learn Topology for animation

Tags: topology

Are there any books or videos that properly demonstrate and explain how to model a character with proper topology? If you want a character where the various parts of the body for one look accurate and deform properly for animation without having a million polygons you need strategically placed edgeloops, this much I know.

But i'm getting really sick of finding dead links, showing not telling and staring at images of completed characters and somehow figuring out what to do on my own.

I recently purchased 'pushing Points: The Topology work book' but that was more focused on removing and controlling triangles, n-gons and poles. Even then it was all on flat surfaces. Didn't help my understanding of edge loops and how you use them since i'd need a character model with broken topology in the first place.

I also purchased an anatomy book for cg artists but that really was just 'here is the human body and some old paintings' Very nice paintings mind.

I respect that subdivision surface is important but it be nice to learn what the edge loops are before subdividing them.

Comment: https://topologyguides.com

Comment: Check this video out: I still refer to it after a cold start:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xls25e08sSg